# Map<String, Object> Json Render in angular table

Tags: java, json, angular, spring, angular7

Implemented one to many using jdbc as per requirement using Map for unique values and list in it for second table,

```
while (rs.next()) {
                String id = rs.getString("REQUEST_ID");
                String name = rs.getString("REQUEST_ITEM_ID");
                String email = rs.getString("REQUEST_ITEM_PARAMETER_VALUE");
                RequestItem requestItem = (RequestItem) requestItemById.get(id);
                if (requestItem == null) {
                    requestItem = new RequestItem(id, name);
                    requestItemById.put(requestItem.getRequestId(), requestItem);
                }
                requestItem.addRequestItemParameter(email);
            }
```

this will generate json in the following format

```
{  
   "5618b87b-4c60-4f38-b18e-053f41ca75a9":{  
      "requestId":"5618b87b-4c60-4f38-b18e-053f41ca75a9",
      "accountNumber":"199e7660-de84-4a98-b245-f45d2d313798",
   },
   "8141c3a4-c35c-4cd5-b9be-dd2dc878ce36":{  
      "requestId":"8141c3a4-c35c-4cd5-b9be-dd2dc878ce36",
      "accountNumber":"f0e9db42-7fe4-4e69-85f5-d0fbd03c7f47",
      "requestItemParameter":[  
         "3608341209",
         "0562254893",
         "0"
      ]
   },
   "5cc5cb01-e7d2-4e44-9abf-08d202ffee9d":{  
      "requestId":"5cc5cb01-e7d2-4e44-9abf-08d202ffee9d",
      "accountNumber":"f7368f6a-3561-4cc7-b8a8-3120d81e5965",
      "requestItemParameter":[  
         "0562254893"
      ]
   },...
```

angular table

```
            <ng-container matColumnDef="requestId">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Request Id </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{rows[$index].requestId}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
            </mat-row>
        </mat-table>
```

I searched it alot on internet to render that json into angular mat table but as angular only accepts array of json, i tried JSON.parse and other java and typscript methods to convert it but no gain.